# Remove GRUB & Edit Boot Loader Records?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, dual-boot

I have installed Linux on a second partition on my MacBook, it also installed the GRUB boot loader which is fine however I have the following problems:

When GRUB loads by default there is no entry for booting into OS X, only Linux.

When I hold option on boot to boot from the OS X partition it doesn’t detect that there is an OS on another partition and only gives me the option for my OS X partition or the Recovery partition.

If possible I would like to remove GRUB and add the Linux partition to my OS X Boot Loader so I have to hold option to boot into Linux as I prefer the look of it and will be using OS X more often so would also be more convenient.

However, failing that I would like to edit my GRUB MBR to add the OS X partition and have it set to auto-boot said partition within 3 seconds if no key is pressed.

If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it, I’ve never ran into similar problems and dug my way out of the hole before but this time I can’t seem to, any and all help will be appreciated!

MacOS Sierra 10.12 (Partition 1)
Linux: Debian Jessie (Partition 3)
MacOS Recovery Partition is Partition 2
GRUB also installed on Partition 3

Comment: @LangLangC I did indeed, updated the original post now.

Answer (score 1):

While it should be possible to either make an EFI/aware GRUB the primary boot loader that chainloads macOS and also the Mac startup manager to recognise Linux, there are some difficulties and downsides to either approach. Both weren't really made for each other and if FileVault2 comes into the picture things leave the pretty phase.

The currently nicest solution for dual booting macOS and Debian would have to be using [The rEFInd Boot Manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html).

> rEFInd is a boot manager, meaning that it presents a menu of options
>   to the user when the computer first starts up, as shown below. rEFInd
>   is not a boot loader, which is a program that loads an OS kernel and
>   hands off control to it. […] Many popular boot
>   managers, such as the Grand Unified Bootloader (GRUB), are also boot
>   loaders, which can blur the distinction in many users' minds.